How can I set "Run as Administrator" on a Link?
I want to set the "Run as Administrator" on a link, specifically the Visual Studio link.
Any pointers as to how I can do this?

Which OS do you ask for? is it linux (because you are asking about file link) or Windows (because you are asking for administartor)?
What is the reason you need to run as administrator?

For Windows. I need it, because Visual Studio needs to run as Administrator if using Service Fabric.
